# Cython: memory views on `numpy` arrays lose `numpy` array features?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Consider the following example:

```
cdef test_function():
    cdef:
        double[:] p1 = np.array([3.2, 2.1])
        double[:] p2 = np.array([0.9, 6.])

    return p1-p2
```

If used, it returns the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef test_function():
    cdef:
        double[:] p1 = np.array([3.2, 2.1])
        double[:] p2 = np.array([0.9, 6.])

    return p1-p2
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython_cell_v3.pyx:354:13: Invalid operand types for '-' (double[:]; double[:])
```

If I am using numpy arrays to initialize the memory view, how can I go about using its functionality? Do I have to somehow do some dereferencing on the memoryviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
cpdef test_function():
    cdef:
        double[:] p1 = np.array([3.2, 2.1])
        double[:] p2 = np.array([0.9, 6.])

    # return p1-p2
    cdef int I
    I = p1.shape[0]
    for i in range(I):
        p1[i] -= p2[i]
    return np.asarray(p1)
print "Test _function", test_function()
```

I iterate on the arrays as though they were 'c' arrays.  And without the final `np.asarray`, it will just display

```
>>> memview.test_function()
<MemoryView of 'ndarray' at 0xb60e772c>
```

See also the example in 
http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#comparison-to-the-old-buffer-support

---

I tried a different function:

```
cpdef test_function1(x):
    cdef:
        int i, N = x.shape[0]
        double[:] p1 = x
    for i in range(N):
        p1[i] *= p1[i]
    return np.asarray(p1)*2

x = np.arange(10.)
print "test_function1 return", test_function1(x)
print "x after test_function1", x
```

As expected, after the function `x` is `x**2`.  But what the function returns is `2*x**2`.

I modify `p1` directly, but end up modifying `x` as well.  I think of `p1` as a view of `x`, but one with reduced functionality.  `np.asarray(p1)` gives it a `numpy` functionality, so I can perform an array `*` on it and return the result (without further modifying `x`).

If instead I'd finished the function with:

```
out = np.asarray(p1)
out *= 2
return out
```

I end up modifying the original `x` as well.  `out` is a numpy view on `x`.  `out` behaves like an array because it is one, not because of some distant link to `x`.

Comment: yes; I'm correcting it.  I was paying more attention as to whether I needed to create a return array or memory view than to arithmetic operator.

Comment: I don't know if I can accept this as an answer simply because I wasn't looking for any solution, but in particular I was wondering how typed memoryviews of numpy arrays could still remember that they were numpy arrays?

Comment: I added a function that shows the memoryview is a `view` with reduced functionality.